# Issue in passing session information for scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I went to this website

```
www4.fmovies.to
```

then I clicked a movie and checked its CDN URL via Inspect->Network
and got below details

```
https://cdn.mcloud.to/stream/sf:i0:q2:h3:p23:l1/LR6ljfLn3hrEjSfrOp19wg/1542603600/i/f/2/nr69r8/hls/480/480-0013.ts

:authority: cdn.mcloud.to
:method: GET
:path: /stream/sf:i0:q2:h3:p23:l1/LR6ljfLn3hrEjSfrOp19wg/1542603600/i/f/2/nr69r8/hls/480/480-0001.ts
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cookie: __cfduid=d0847f9ac6d9a8da1dd131d1a0a91ea991542533053; _ga=GA1.2.485859786.1542533055; _gid=GA1.2.1916946057.1542533055; _gat=1
origin: https://mcloud.to
referer: https://mcloud.to/embed/@P@O8SE2916SEOA5?sub.file=https%253A%252F%252Fstatic1.akacdn.ru%252Fsubtitle%252F40039.vtt%253Fv1&ui=oAhi567w9OQEhJWEdbl0s%40Ep0Ir2VvG1xiK9JqKx
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36
```

created header information using the above information and then ran

```
request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

But am getting 403 Not Authorized. What is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `referer` header that is the `src` attribute of video content `iframe` that looks like

```
<iframe src="https://mcloud.to/embed/@9@4ZS04Z10SWOE5?ui=pwxi4Kjr6%40wHmIqHcrl0yeFfpYqUUIW1wCKlJr6x" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="yes" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

The code looks like

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'cache-control': 'no-cache', 'referer': 'https://mcloud.to/embed/@9@4ZS04Z10SWOE5?ui=pwxi4Kjr6%40wHmIqHcrl0yeFfpYqUUIW1wCKlJr6x'}

requests.get('https://cdn.mcloud.to/stream/sf:i0:q2:h2:p24:l1/WjLDZuCBHmtyv63lT-RoVQ/1542603600/g/c/0/rj0m0m/hls/480/480-0000.ts', headers=headers)
```

Comment: If you run it, you would see that it gives 403

Comment: What exact page you want to visit? I see that actually click on movie image should reditrect you to something like https://www4.fmovies.to/film/the-girl-in-the-spiders-web.nrvxk/k5qrp9, so maybe you should try correct URL?

Comment: that is fine but the actual movie is streamed. And if you checked network of inspect element of browser, movie is actually streamed and played via  https://cdn.mcloud.to/stream/sf:i0:q2:h2:p24:l1/WjLDZuCBHmtyv63lT-RoVQ/1542603600/g/c/0/rj0m0m/hls/480/480-0000.ts and more 0001, 0002 and likes. But you cannot open these URLs with requests

Comment: @Tahseen , update your question with all the headers you use in request

Comment: Already mentioned the headers am using in the request. You can see that in the question

Comment: @Tahseen , I meant I want to see how they looks like in your headers dictionary, as provided headers are just raw text.. check updated. For me this returns `200` status

Comment: my mistake was I was using incorrect spelling of 'referer'. I used 'referrer' and realized so after seeing your code. But thanks and I will mark your answer right

Comment: @Tahseen , I'll update my answer in few minutes to show how to scrape that URL from page with movie

Comment: Thanks. If you can mention, how to scrape that iframe src URL from the movie page, that would be great. Thanks a ton

Comment: @Tahseen , page source doesn't contain that `iframe`: it comes from somewhere else, so it might take some time for me to find it :)

Comment: If you do iframe search on page source you would find that indeed on the page is a javascript, which at run time, decrypts a string with it to generate this decrypted iframe and let the browser execute it

Comment: @Tahseen , OK, so that iframe data comes from XHR: `requests.get('https://www4.fmovies.to/ajax/episode/info?ts=1542542400&_=1121&id=3mwr28&server=28', headers={'referer': 'https://www4.fmovies.to/film/the-grinch.pjxl4/3mwr28'}).json()['target']`... `ts` parameter seam to be static (`ts=1542542400`), `server` is also static (`server=28`), `id` is the movie id that is added to movie page URL e.g. `id=3mwr28`, but for now I can't understand where that `_` parameter value comes from... This `_=1121` value is the key to success :) If to find where it comes from then you'll be able to get everything

Comment: looks like it is some token, because if you change it with another correct one also of a different link, it gives token error. Although ts also changes but it is replaceable

Comment: @Tahseen , I made some investigation and it looks like both `ts` and `_` are timestamps parameters for caching control. `ts` is something that you might get with `print(time.time())`,  but still not sure how to simulate these two params correctly...

Comment: check this out https://github.com/coder-alpha/FMoviesPlus.bundle/blob/master/Contents/Code/fmovies.py and in this you see serverts = str(((int(time.time())/3600)*3600))

Comment: @Tahseen , yes , `ts` is the time stamp parameter, but what is `_`?  I found that this is some kind of jQuery.ajax parameter, but still don't know how ho define its value

Comment: it is the key token. That is also mentioned in the program. And am backtracking it. You can also see it mentioned as token or key in the same module

Comment: @Tahseen I've checked almost everything and could not find the way to extract value for `_` key... Did you find it?

Comment: no but that link of the program on github that I sent you, it indeed calculating it from the cookie. It is calling it token key / token id